# Attempted to import .csv into mySQL using workbench, but only imports 7 rows?

Tags: mysql, import, mysql-workbench, csv

To start, I'm still a relative SQL noob so this question could have an obvious answer that I'm just missing. I'm trying to start a big practice project in my spare time using a dataset which has ~191000 rows and ~150 columns of data.

Attempting to use mySQLworkbench's table data import wizard to import the dataset after saving it as a .csv. When I run the import process, it successfully imports only 7 rows but doesn't give any error messages to indicate what stopped it.

What is preventing more than 7 rows from importing? How do I fix it?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: @mustaccio *Use the `copy` command in the MySQL command line client* - no such command. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-commands.html

Comment: *When I run the import process, it successfully imports only 7 rows but doesn't give any error messages to indicate what stopped it.* Import using CLI (`LOAD DATA INFILE`).

Comment: Check the input. Very likely the 8th line contains something that cannot be imported with the given settings.